# Flask edit form submit truble

Tags: python, flask, routes, submit

Objects

```
class MyObj:    
    def __init__(self, data_dict):
        self.id = ''
        self.name = ''
        self.minDescription = ''
        self.descriptions = ''

class MyObjForm(Form):
    name = StringField('name')
    minDescription = StringField('minDescription')
    descriptions = TextAreaField('descriptions')
```

Routings

This good work in "POST" and "GET" mode. Submit button have a good reactions when click.

```
@app.route("/create", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def create():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyObjForm(request.form)
        if form.validate():
            new_obj = MyObj(request.form)
            return redirect(url_for("/"))
        else:
            return render_template('create.html', form=form)
    else:
        return render_template('create.html', form=MyObjForm())
```

When i route in "GET" mode my code is good work and view have old object data but click on submit button is not have any reactions.

```
@app.route("/edit/<id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def edit(id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        old_obj = d.get_by_id(id)
        form = MyObjForm(obj=old_obj)
        return render_template('create.html', form=form, id=id)
    else:
        #never entry
        pass
```

HTML 'create.html'

```
<form method="post" role="form">
    {{ form.csrf }}
    {{ macros.render_field(form.name) }}
    {{ macros.render_field(form.minDescription) }}
    {{ macros.render_field(form.descriptions) }}
    <input class="btn special" type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

I try this:

```
<form method="post" role="form" action="{{ url_for('edit', id=id) }}">
```

and this:

```
class MyObjForm(Form):    
id = StringField()
```

any not have a progress :(

Wath wrong?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what exactly your question is. Do you get an error? If not what behavior do you expect that isn't there. Also you indentation in your `MyObjForm` class is off.

Comment: I not get any error. I expected that i can use one html template to implement the methods of adding and editing the product.
But in case of product editing the form does not go to the edit method and any nothing happens when you click the save button.

Comment: I identified the problem :)
If not use args ('obj=new_obj') when MyObjForm create the save button call my route in post mode :)
But now there is no data in the form that i want to change :(

Answer (score 0):

I identified the problem:

1. If not use args ('obj=new_obj') when MyObjForm create the save button call my route in post mode as well
2. When i published the question too simplified the description of the problem. Realy MyObjForm include BooleanField:

   `class MyObjForm(Form):
       name = StringField('name')
       minDescription = StringField('minDescription')
       descriptions = TextAreaField('descriptions')
       isArchive = BooleanField('Is not public')`
3. I didn't notice the checkbox stopped showing up on the form for reasons unknown to me. The standard rendering method was used for output:

   `{{ macros.render_field2(form.isArchive) }}

   {% macro render_field2(field) %}
   {{ field.label }}
   {{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
   {% if field.errors %}
       {% for error in field.errors %}
           {{ error }}
       {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endmacro %}`
4. To solve the issue with the visualization applied the following:

   `<input type="checkbox" id="isArchive" name="isArchive">
   <label for="isArchive">{{ form.isArchive.label }}</label>
   {% for error in form.isArchive.errors %}
       <li><font color="red">{{ error }}</font></li>
   {% endfor %}`
5. One last thing. Did not notice how, but the form also stopped working when you add an object, no longer pass validation. And the reason was `{{ form.csrf }}}` which had to be replaced with `{{ form.csrf_token() }}`. Still had to remove the validation parameters for BooleanField.

Now the problem is partially solved.I associate these issues with the installation of the flask-security component. Unfortunately, I was not able to make a normal display of the checkbox, but at least I can move on.

If anyone has any idea how these things can be related to each other or what I'm wrong please let me know. I do not want to leave gaps in knowledge.